# 389-ds and openldap client setup

Tags: ldap, openldap, sssd, 389-ds

I am working towards a proof concept:

I have installed 389-dc on centos and enabled ssl via a self-signed certificate. (after a lot of reading)
I  can see the port 636 is listening on the centos server

Now, i need to know what do i do to setup client centos machines to login in using userids on the 389-ds server.

I read from some sites telling not to use pam and nss. and only use SSSD. i am new to this side of the world, what is the best recommendation on this area, please advice.

Thanks
Jenefa

Answer (score 0):

The config will vary depending on your server, but you essentially need to:
a) configure sssd.conf
b) run authconfig with arguments that suit your setup

There are plenty of examples online but I found these man pages invaluable to do almost exactly what you are attempting (except with ca-signed certificates):
* sssd.conf
* sssd
* sssd-ldap
* (and authconfig --help)

The default file at /etc/sssd/sssd.conf has some useful comments and examples too.
LDAP authentication isssd and authconfig hide a lot of the more